# Update pattern for subplots d3 v4

Tags: d3.js

I'm working on a d3 project that has multiple sub-plots with updating data. I have a working example below, but I think I might be overcomplicating the `update()` pattern. I didn't include an `exit()` because the data is consistent (there's always the same amount of divisions, teams and values).

d3 experts: does this look right to you? What would you modify to make it more performant / maintainable? Should I invoke a function for each component of the chart? e.g. a function for building the division charts, a function for building the team charts, a function for building the bars, etc.

I'm interested in learning how to write clean maintainable d3 code, so please pass along any resources if you have any.

Thanks!

```js
const dataset1 = [
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 5},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 7},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 9},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 1},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 1},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 1},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 7},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 7},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 6},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 9},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 5},
]

const dataset2 = [
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 1},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 4},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 1", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 6},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 2", "value": 9},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 5},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 1", "team": "team 3", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 8},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 1},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 1", "value": 2},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 5},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 2", "value": 7},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 4},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 3},
 {"division": "division 2", "team": "team 3", "value": 8},
]

function updateChart(data) {
  
  // Divisions
  var divisions = d3.nest().key(d=>d.division).entries(data); 
  var divisionCharts = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg").data(divisions, d=>d.key);
  var divisionChartsEnter = divisionCharts.enter().append("svg").attr("width", 200).attr("height", 75);
  
  // Teams
  var teamCharts = divisionCharts.merge(divisionChartsEnter).selectAll("svg")
    .data(d => d3.nest().key(d=>d.team).entries(d.values), d=>d.key)
  var teamChartsEnter = teamCharts.enter().append("svg").attr("x", (d,i) => i*50);
  
  // Values for each team
  var bars = teamCharts.merge(teamChartsEnter).selectAll("rect").data(d => d.values);
  var barsEnter = bars.enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d,i)=>i*12)
    .attr("width", 10)
  bars.merge(barsEnter)
    .transition()
    .attr("height", d=>d.value*10)
  
  // Toggle dataset
  currDataset = data == dataset1 ? dataset2 : dataset1;
}

let currDataset = dataset1;
updateChart(currDataset);

d3.select("#updateData").on("click", () => updateChart(currDataset))
```

```html
<p><button id="updateData">Update Data</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use scales (`d3.scaleBand` and `d3.scaleLinear`) for the xAxis and the yAxis? Hard coding it makes it hard to modify the size of the SVG and the number of elements. What is the reason to use 6 barchats instead of 1?

Comment: Your question is both too broad and opinion-based for Stack Overflow. Since you have a perfectly working code and seek for a review, I suggest you post your question at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com), with the `d3.js` tag.

Comment: @rioV8 I didn't include the `d3.scaleBand` and `d3.scaleLinear` for the axis for simplicity. I include those in my larger codebase.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I didn't know about Code Review. I'll post it there, thanks!